# MySql Query return wrong values in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, recordset

Using the following query I need to display only the records marked with the year "2014" in the month "02":

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 c.sno,
 c.cCode,
 c.caseNumber,
 c.dateOriginalInstitution,
 c.date_remanded,
 c.plaintiff,
 c.respondant 
FROM
  cases c,
  chronologicallists ch 
WHERE (
 (YEAR(dateOriginalInstitution) = '2014' AND MONTH(dateOriginalInstitution) = '02') 
 OR 
 (YEAR(dateOfTransferInstituion) = '2014' AND MONTH(dateOfTransferInstituion) = '02') 
 OR 
 (YEAR(date_restored) = '2014' AND MONTH(date_restored) = '02')
) 
AND c.inTheCourt = '578' AND c.sno = ch.caseSno
```

[image]

I'm still getting 2011 and 2012 in the result set?

Please help me with this.

Comment: Show `dateOfTransferInstituion` column to, I guess it must be having the "2014" record.

Comment: maybe you should use a `LIKE` clause in there to compare it if `dateOfTransferInstitution` has a similar looking date stamp to `dateOriginalInstitution` for instance `dateOriginalInstitution LIKE '2014-02-%'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of your `OR` condition.

You might be having `year` value as `2014` in either `dateOfTransferInstituion` or `date_restored` columns but not in `dateOriginalInstitution` column

Comment: As i have checked my columns there is nothing but 0000-00-00 in all other date columns where only  the dateOriginalInstaitution column has the correct date values? So, it should disply only record related to dateOriginalInstitution column.

Comment: Show sample records with the said columns in result set. Example query:  `select dateOriginalInstitution, dateOfTransferInstituion, date_restored from cases where 2014 in ( year(dateOriginalInstitution), year(dateOfTransferInstituion), year(date_restored) ) and '02' in ( month(dateOriginalInstitution), month(dateOfTransferInstituion), month(date_restored) )`

Comment: Yes you are right, it rocks now... Thanks FancyPants

Comment: Ravinder my query is the same thing your but your query is very good in comparesion of my query.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 columns responsible for this `dateOriginalInstitution`,`dateOfTransferInstituion`,`dateOfTransferInstituion` that you should check

Use `AND` instead of `OR` and mind to display `dateOfTransferInstituion` for you to know if
they passed your `WHERE` condition.

```
WHERE (
 (YEAR(dateOriginalInstitution) = '2014' AND MONTH(dateOriginalInstitution) = '02') 
 AND 
 (YEAR(dateOfTransferInstituion) = '2014' AND MONTH(dateOfTransferInstituion) = '02') 
 AND 
 (YEAR(date_restored) = '2014' AND MONTH(date_restored) = '02')
```

Comment: No, when i use "ADN" there is nothing to be displayed because i will then search for the same values in the where clause, and the resultant recordset will be shown blank.